# which is the better way to show data in iPhone app:-create our database or use website database

Tags: sqlite

I have 30.000 data and I want to search all so that when I click on any of the product it show's the detail of that product. How can I do this and what's the most powerful solution?

Comment: It depends on so many things... How often will it be updated, do you have to work everywhere, and a ton of other concerns. In general, however, just pick one and go with it.

Answer (score 0):

Try generating a RSS (XML) feed or do some research into JSON, you can find parsers for both to bring the data into the app. Then use NSPredicate to filter or search.

Generating xml feed from SQL table:
http://www.pixel2life.com/forums/index.php?/topic/24572-creating-a-php-sql-rss-feed/